# are all NP problems made up of P problems?

Tags: computational-complexity

are all NP problems made up of P problems? that is, can NP problems be thought of as an accumulation of P problems? or can NP problems be divided up into a series of P problems?

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by divided up in a series of P-problems. Sure, you can in some sense divide your problem into P-problems, but the NUMBER of such sub-problems, is not a polynomial in your parameter $n$ (unless P=NP).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is yes. Suppose that $A$ is any NP problem, so there is a polynomial time algorithm $p$ such that $a\in A$ just in case there is some $b$ (of size at most $q(|a|)$,  where $q$ is a fixed polynomial) such that $p$ accepts the pair $(a,b)$. Let $A_b$ be the set of $a$ such that $b$ has size at most $q(|a|)$ and $p$ accepts $(a,b)$. So each $A_b$ is in the class $P$, and $A$ is clearly the union $$A=\bigcup_b A_b.$$ So every NP problem is an accumulation of P problems in a natural way.

Comment: I afraid that I find those expressions to be either wrong,  meaningless or open.